# Retrieving generic types java to create a framework

Tags: java, c++, generics, arguments

I want to retrieve the underlying generic class's argument to be used in some other class to create required framework, for example I would have done something like this in C++:

```
template <typename I> class Input {};
template <typename O> class Output{};
template <typename I, typename O> class Calculable : public Input<I>, Output<O>
{
    using inputType = I;
    using outputType = O;
};
template <typename S> class Example : public Calculable <typename S::inputType, typename S::outputType>{};
```

But I am stuck with the same in java.
the Example class in Java is like:

```
public class Example<T> extends Calculable<get T's inputType, get T's outputType>{}
What do I write here                            ^                   ^
```

As I am a novice to java, can someone please help me with this, answers appreciated.

Comment: You can’t.  Although Java generics visually resemble C++ templates, they are something different.  Java does not retain that information at runtime;  it is only used at compile time to enforce type safety.  You can, however, require callers to pass objects of type `Class<I>` and `Class<O>` to the constructor.

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritence so the closest thing you can get is try to rewrite your code and make Input and Output interfaces and have Calculable implement these two interfaces.